# How to determine origin of a tweet using long and lat

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm really confused about a section from my homework, its not graded or anything but I still want to be able to complete and understand it.

I'm trying to "approximate" regions corresponding to their timezones (not real data). So Eastern (**P1. P2. P3, P4**, Pacific(**P7, P8, P9, P10**), Mountain
(**P5, P6, P7, P8**) , Central(**P3,P4,P5,P6**)....

im trying to determine the origin of a tweet, by determining which region the latitude and longitude of the tweet belongs (I have a txt file and all the tweets have a long, lat number associated with it. for example: `[36.970152730000002, -84.090040380000005] 4 2011-09-02 17:40:11 Chicken flatheads at taco bell my life is complete)`. The values of the points are: (rectangle)

```
p1 = (49.189787, -67.444574) 
p2 = (24.660845, -67.444574)
p3 = (49.189787, -87.518395) 
p4 = (24.660845, -87.518395) 
p5 = (49.189787, -101.998892)
p6 = (24.660845, -101.998892) 
p7 = (49.189787, -115.236428) 
p8 = (24.660845, -115.236428) 
p9 = (49.189787, -125.242264)
p10 = (24.660845, -125.242264)
```

For example, if a tweet is inbetween p1, p2, p3, p4 then they are from Eastern. How would I do this?

Comment: As a first step you would need the coordinate polygons defining the time zone. Then you need a suitable library to map the coordinates to the polygons.

Comment: we are not as bad as all that. if the homework help request comes with a bit of code and can convince us that a genuine attempt has been made, some of us will help :)

Comment: @e4c5, and I always provide what ive done! But this point Ive let my instructor know I had know idea how you use the longitude and lats & he promised to get to me but didnt (n)

Comment: but as a programmer what you are being trained for is to solve problems, so a bit of research on geographic data would help you here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the regions are rectangles.

Just check the value of the lat, long against the "border" values.

So, for Eastern:

```
if lat >= 24.660845 and lat < 49.189787 and long <= -67.444574 and long > -87.518395:
    return True
```

Or, if the regions are sequential as you've shown (and only changing in longitude), just check that.

Of course, if the regions are irregular polygons, it would be a whole new problem.

**Edit**:
One approach would be to create a Region class with a contains(lat, long) method:

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, lat_tuple, long_tuple):
        self.lat_tuple = lat_tuple
        self.long_tuple = long_tuple

    def contains(self, lat, long):
        return self.lat_tuple[0] <= lat and lat < self.lat_tuple[1] and\
               self.long_tuple[0] <= long and long < self.long_tuple[1]
```

And use it as:

```
eastern = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-87.518395, -67.444574))
print(eastern.contains(34.0, - 70.10))
print(eastern.contains(14.0, - 70.10))
```

Comment: Yes the values are rectangles

Comment: So that ones for eastern, how would I say that specicifically? should I add a for statement at the top? Like For Eastern?

Comment: You could do it in various ways... 

Try creating a Region class with the border values as its member. 
And then write a contains(lat, long) function that takes in the lat, long values of point and returns a boolean representing whether that point lies in the region or not.

Comment: @New Please look at the edit. I have added in the Region class. Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually how did you get the numbers for the print statement?

Comment: I copied your method and did central = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-101.998892, -87.518395))
mountain = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-115.236428, -101.998892))
pacific = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-125.242264, -115.236428)) does that seem correct?

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I am trying it out now! Ill let you know :)

Comment: Hi, it works! Yes, but I was wondering if theres another way to do this? A more simpler and understanding way. If not its ok

Comment: It works fine, but the number that ive gotten for the amount of tweets is high. did I input them correctly? eastern = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-87.518395, -67.444574))
central = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-101.998892, -87.518395))
mountain = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-115.236428, -101.998892))
pacific = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-125.242264, -115.236428))

Comment: Yes. You're inputting them correctly. Hmm... if you want a simpler way, you could use a bunch of if-else constructs. 

region = ''

if ___:
    region = 'eastern'
elif __:
    region = 'central'

And so on

Comment: Youre so much help. I asked another question. Do u mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644895/adding-scores-depending-on-their-regions-long-latitude-in-python-asisstance