# Adding scores depending on their regions (long/latitude) in python asisstance

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file containing over 200 tweets and im trying to total the number of the scores for all the tweets in that region (more info below)
A basic tweet looks like:

```
[30.346168930000001, -97.73518] 0 2011-08-29 04:54:22 Best vacation of my life #byfar
```

so the regions are defined as

```
class Region:
    def __init__(self, lat_tuple, long_tuple):
        self.lat_tuple = lat_tuple
        self.long_tuple = long_tuple

    def contains(self, lat, long):
        return self.lat_tuple[0] <= lat and lat < self.lat_tuple[1] and\
               self.long_tuple[0] <= long and long < self.long_tuple[1]

 eastern = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-87.518395, -67.444574))
 central = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-101.998892, -87.518395))
 mountain = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-115.236428, -101.998892))
 pacific = Region((24.660845, 49.189787), (-125.242264, -115.236428))
```

So I already was able to determine how the amount of scores for each of the sentences like this :

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    sentiments = {word: int(value)
                 for word, value in
                 (line.split(",") for line in f)}

with open('sentences.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        values = Counter(word for word in line.split() if word in sentiments)
        if not values:
            continue
score_Tweet = (sum(values[word]*sentiments[word] for word in values)) // (len(values))
```

And now I just need to add the scores depending on their regions. Ive tried many like if statements and def, but all of them bring an error

Comment: Can you include the error message, where the error is occurring, and what your words.txt and sentences.txt files look like?

Comment: What is the final score supposed to be? And what does "add scores depending on their regions" mean?

Comment: Im just confused about this in general. I might just hand this in as it is as accept the fail mark @BijayGurung